# Setting parent record field value based on Maximum Child record field value

Tags: ms-access, vba, dataset, ms-access-2007, setvalue

I am working with MS Access 2007.
I have a table called `[tblDonors]` linked to child records in a table called `[tblReceipts]`.
I am trying to set the value of a new Boolean(y/n) field `[tblDonors].[blInactive]`.  I would like to run a script which goes through every record in `[tblDonors]` and set the `[blInactive]` field to `"True"` if the most recent receipt year(`[tblReceipts].[Date]`) is older than year(`now())-2`.
Here is my query:

> SELECT tblDonors.ID, Year([tblReceipts].[Date]) AS [Year], tblDonors.Active
>
> FROM tblDonors 
> LEFT JOIN tblReceipts ON tblDonors.ID = tblReceipts.ID
>
> WHERE (((Year([tblReceipts].[Date]))>=Year(Now())-2))
>
> ORDER BY Donors.ID;

This query shows the parent record multiple times if the donor has donated more than once within the past two years, which creates duplicate records in a report.
How can I go through each record of this query to set `tblDonors.Active` to `TRUE` using `VBA`?
The following helps demonstrate the gist of what I am attempting to accomplish.

```
    Function fnActivity()                     'locates active donors

        For each record in recordset          'Go through each record in the query...
            record.[Active].Value = True      '...and flag as active member.
        Next record

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you could accomplish that by setting [blInactive] to `Yes` for everyone...

```
UPDATE tblDonors SET blInactive = Yes
```

...and then update the current donors like this:

```
UPDATE tblDonors SET blInactive = No
WHERE ID IN 
    (
        SELECT ID FROM tblReceipts 
        WHERE Year([tblReceipts].[Date]) >= (Year(Now()) - 2)
    )
```

Comment: That did the charm.  Thank you for helping resolve an issue that has been causing much annoyance.